# how to upload large file to server using chunk in angular

Tags: angular, file, rxjs, upload, chunks

I want to chunk a large file and upload it to the server
how to send a post request to a large file to a server using chunk file upload and RxJS in angular 2

Answer (score -1):

I used a javascript to upload the file to an api which needs a token.

```
<button id="upload-button" onclick="uploadFile()"> Upload </button>
```

Use this script in the index file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    async function uploadFile() {
    let formData = new FormData();      
    formData.append("token", window.sessionStorage.getItem("token"));      
    formData.append("file", fileupload.files[0]);
    console.log("Name " +formData.get("file").name);
    console.log("Token " +formData.get("token"));

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/upload', {
      method: "POST", 
      mode: 'no-cors',
      credentials: 'omit',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: formData
    });

    console.log(response);
    if(response){
      console.log("File uploaded");
      alert('The file has been uploaded successfully.');
    } else {
      throw new Error('Network response was not OK');
    }
}
</script>
```